# How do I hide /sites/default/files from URLs?

Tags: files, uri

I want to upload files to their normal directory under /sites/default/files/. So let's assume I have example.pdf uploaded to sites/sites/default/files/manuals/example.pdf.

I want the links to files look like http://example.com/manuals/example.pdf. I think it's simpler and looks more professional.

How can I achieve it with Drupal?

Comment: I was sure it was asked, but I can't find it. If it will not be marked as a duplicate, I'll post an answer in a day or two. Unless someone will want to answer, of course.

Comment: easy for image https://drupal.org/project/image_field_url_replacer

Comment: There was a module that did that once upon a time. Doesn't seem to exist any more though

Comment: @Bala I've seen and used solution with mod_rewrite on receiving end and preprocess functions on url generating end - and that's what I planned to post. But I'm perfectly open for other answers.

Comment: @Clive I recall seeing solution here, but it seems to be popular demand - strange I can't find module on Drupal.org or question here. Something doesn't feel quite right, especially given that it's not *that* hard to achieve. Maybe it's only hard to find?

Comment: @Mołot Yeah it's called something un-intuitive - like 'pretty file URLs' or something - or maybe even more obscure. I'm firmly of the opinion that the length/path depth of an image (or any other file) is completely irrelevant, so I'll stay out of this one ;)

Comment: @Clive there are Drupal developers that are forced to use opinion provided by marketing department ;)

Comment: @Mołot Marketing folks literally run from my desk when they come to me with that crap ;D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[File Aliases](https://drupal.org/project/file_aliases) module allows you to use token customizable aliases for your uploaded files, giving you the ability to keep your file system organized as per usual while providing clean looking paths (i.e., no more '/sites/default/files/').

> - Customizable File Alias field using Node tokens.
>     Support for:
>
>   - Drupal core Upload module.
>   - FileField module.
>   - ImageField module.
>   - Image module.
>   - Comment Upload module.
> - Support for Private and Public file systems.
> - Support for Views output (Fields and Nodes).
> - Support for FileField Paths Retroactive and Active Updating.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Nice!

Comment: Good catch :) I'll probably accept it, but post the manual way later anyway.

Comment: Does this work with the CDN module?

Comment: @Mołot what do you expect, I can't understand what you are asking about the manual way

Comment: @Bala damn, forgot about it. I mean you can make Apache accept links without /sites/*/files by using mod_rewrite, and cut that part from links using MYMODULE_preprocess_links(). Sorry I totally forgot to post that.

Comment: @Mołot sorry, honestly I don't have any experience with this before, I thought file alias module will do the stuff without any manual intervention.

Comment: @Bala it should. It usually does. But for the guy who inspired me post this question it was too buggy to use, and there is a way to do it without this module. That's all. But your answer is fine and upvoted by me all right :)